# What Are Instances In Server Work Queues Metrics Mean?

Tags: windows, performance, performancecounter, perfmon

I am trying understand what are the instances mean from any of the Server Work Queues metrics.

For example:

Object:
Server Work Queues \ Work Item Shortages

Instance:
0
1
2
...
...
Blocking Queues
SMB2 Blocking 0
...
...
SMB2 NonBlocking 0
...
...

I am assuming 0...15 is the nonblocking queues for each logical processor and there is only one Blocking Queues. This is the NonBlocking / Blocking pair for SMB (1)?

In conjunction SMB2 Blocking 1 - 15 and SMB2 NonBlocking 1 - 15 is the Blocking and NonBlocking pair for only SMB 2.

If so, then I should not even care 0 - 15 and Blocking Queues, if I am using SMB2, correct?